# Check if image has been loaded

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Hello i have this code:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(contact.PreviewPhoto, UriKind.Relative));
a.photo.Source = image;

contact.PreviewPhoto="https://files.test.lv/public/photos/h66/38B83D35-15B5-4872-8CE5-F3E50001E921.jpg";
```

How can i determine if image has been loaded?

Because sometimes internet connection can get lost, or the link is blank, how to replace it in that case?

Comment: Check the ImageOpened event: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.image.imageopened(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for check image has loade . But here is the sample for the image has exist or not

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("YourImageUrl");
request.Method = "HEAD";


try
{
    request.GetResponse();
    return true;
}
catch
{
   return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, thanks to Fabrice, the correct answer will be:

```
   BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(contact.PreviewPhoto));
                            image.ImageFailed += (s, e) =>
                            {
                                image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/no-picture.png", UriKind.Relative));
                                a.photo.Source = image;
                            };
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're more looking for NOT loaded instead of loaded...

You can listen to BitmapImage's events like DecodeFailed or DownloadFailed: (msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage_events.aspx).

If a.photo is of type Image, then you can also listen to the events ImageFailed and ImageOpened (msdn.microsoft.com/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.controls.image_events(v=vs.105).aspx)